# ngx-serial/ RS232 protocol / Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, serial-port

I am really new to Angular and I am having trouble with an RS232 protocol project.
I want to use ngx-serial (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-serial) in a project.
Even though the writer's cloned repository (https://github.com/archocron/ngx-serial-example) works fine, I can connect the serial port when I'm trying to import the library in my own angular project I get an error.

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:2:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-serial' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { NgxSerial } from 'ngx-serial';
```

but I have already tried the following:

```
npm i ngx-serial
npm install ngx-serial
```

The package.json containing ngx-serial:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "ngx-serial": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap-scss": "^5.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
...
```

And the App.Component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxSerial } from 'ngx-serial';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Display System';

  serial: NgxSerial;
  port: any;

  constructor() {
    this.serial = new NgxSerial(this.dataHandler);
  }

  dataHandler(data: string) {
    console.log("From arduino -> " + data);
  }

  connect() {
    if (!this.port) {
      this.serial.connect((port: any) => {
        this.port = port;
      });
    }
  }


  close() {
    if (this.port)
      this.serial.close((port: any) => {
        this.port = port;

      });
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I still get the error. Any suggestions?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can I see your package.json?

Comment: I couldn't comment code so I edit the post with the package.json

Comment: Ok, looks good. I have test it in a brand new project and all work as well. Can I see your App.Component.ts, too, please?

Comment: I edited  the question with the App.Component.ts

Comment: I don't know... looka all good. You only can try to delete the "node_modules" folder, install all again (npm install) and restart your app

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
npm install ngx-serial --legacy-peer-deps
```

instead of

```
npm install ngx-serial
```

And it worked!